# screen in LSB init script fails to register

Tags: linux, bash, debian, gnu-screen, init.d

Similar issue as: [Using screen to startup a minecraft server(linux debian)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22430578/using-screen-to-startup-a-minecraft-serverlinux-debian)
System:
Ubuntu 14.04
amd64

I am trying to run a daemon that runs on bootup so I have decided to use init scripts. I would like to interact with the daemons console but not have it outputting to the main screen. I've decided to use the screen utility to create a screen named "minecraft" to run the daemon in the background and then use screen -R to reattach to it when I need to run commands.

The problem I have exist on bootup where, after logging in, I see the process successfully started with the screen command but screen -ls and screen -R yeild no results (No Sockets found in /var/run/screen/S-root). I run all screen commands as sudo since the init script boots the server.

My init script:

```
#! /bin/sh
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          minecraft
# Required-Start:    $local_fs $network
# Required-Stop:     $local_fs $network
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: Minecraft Server
# Description:       Minecraft Server bootup script
### END INIT INFO

PATH=/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin
DESC="Minecraft server instance"
NAME=minecraft
DAEMON_USER=minecraft
DAEMON=minecraft_server.1.8.jar
MCPATH=/home/minecraft/server
SCRIPTNAME=/etc/init.d/$NAME
MAX_HEAP=1024
MIN_HEAP=1024

do_start()
{
    echo "Starting..."
    cd $MCPATH
    screen -dmS $NAME java -Xmx${MAX_HEAP}M -Xms${MIN_HEAP}M -jar $DAEMON nogui
}
```

Now this init script works perfectly if I run it manually through ssh (sudo service minecraft restart), then I can see my screens!

$ sudo screen -ls
There is a screen on:
        1666.minecraft  (14-10-23 12:35:56 PM)  (Detached)
1 Socket in /var/run/screen/S-root.

But whenever I reboot the machine, the screen command will not create the screen but it will look like it has under ps:

$ps aux | grep mine
SCREEN -dmS minecraft java -X ...

**TL;DR** (hopefully not)
Init script using screen to daemonize process works via command-line, however, will not work after ran from the boot process.

I suspect that this is because screen depends on another process like tty terminals or the like but I can figure out what Required-Start I need to change the order of the init script

**Edit 1:**

Tried adding: required-start: screen-cleanup from the following:
http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Tutorials/Server_startup_script

Didnt work..

**Edit 2:**

I fixed the issue using a *sleep* and push to background.

```
bash -c "sleep 30 && screen -dmS $NAME java -Xmx...nogui"&   <--- important
```

But I would like to know how to delay this init script till the very end.

**Edit 3:**

Found a way to suspend the initscript to run at the latest as possible.

My issue: My ubuntu version 14.04 uses upstart (/etc/init) mixed with sysv (/etc/init.d). I am using an init script style which is old and they are trying to phase out. Depending on services with Required-Start with sysv does not seem to work properly so I modified my runlevels to make minecraft start as late as possible.

```
$ update-rc.d -f minecraft remove
$ update-rc.d -f minecraft start 99 S . stop 31 0 1 6 .
```

What does this all mean? Read up on LSB init scripts, essentially minecraft is told to run at priority 99 when starting (latest) and 31 when stopping (which is a random number I picked).

I suppose this question is answered although I'd like to know if I am right.